# Drupal theme function not being overridden

Tags: drupal, function, themes

I'm using Ubercart and I'm attempting to override the following theme function `theme_address_pane()` which is in `uc_cart_checkout_pane.inc`. So I wrote the following function in `template.php`:

```
function mytheme_address_pane($form) {
    return "asdf";
}
```

However, it isn't replacing anything with "asdf". What could I be doing wrong?

Edit: The `devel` module reports the function being called as `theme_address_pane`, not my overridden one.

Comment: Have you cleared the cache? Theme functions are only detected when the theme registry is built, which will happen after the cache is cleared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever dealing with the theming system, you often have to clear the cache to see it come to effect. Not the entire cache, just the theme registry. Here drupal stores info about which theming function and template to use. So whenever you want to change which function or template to use, you have to clear the cache.

When changing a function or template directly, clearing the cache wont be needed. Drupal wont cache the function or template, itself, but only the location/name. So you can happily alter in your theme function once you have made sure drupal has registered it.

Answer (score 2):

If you put the following at the top of your template.php file (inside the php tag):

> `drupal_flush_all_caches();`

It will clear the cache everytime the page loads. This way you won't have to flush the caches manually. However, be SURE to REMOVE it before the theme gets published, or you will see a HUGE performance hit on every page load!

Answer (score 0):

To alter a theme function in Drupal 6 you need to implement [`hook_theme_registry_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/6).